# SQL Lag() across multiple rows

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to populate `NULL` results with the previous non-null result using MS Azure SQL.

Given the query below, should the `Status` column not replace the `NULL` values with the previous non-null value? The docs for `Lag(...)` suggest it will read the previous result row so '2015-04-03' for `athlete:7` should copy the value from `2015-04-02` which was in turn read from `2015-04-01`. But in this case `Lag` appears to get the table value not the coalesced result row value. Any idea why?

I've seen [alternative ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440623/applying-lag-to-multiple-rows-with-a-null-value) to perform this *fill from above* behaviour but they don't really explain what is happening and I'm struggling to understand them, can anyone explain (like I'm stupid) how to get the behaviour i need?

Helpfully, when we transition to the next athleteId there is always a Status for their first day.

```
Declare @AvailabilityDates table
      ( row_index int,
        AthleteId int,
        AvailabilityDate date,
        Status int);

select 
    row_index , 
    AthleteId ,
    AvailabilityDate,
    COALESCE(
            Status, 
            LAG(Status) over (order by row_index)       
        ) as Status
from @AvailabilityDates 


row_index   AthleteId   AvailabilityDate    Status
1           7           2015-04-01          2
2           7           2015-04-02          2
3           7           2015-04-03          NULL
4           7           2015-04-04          NULL
5           7           2015-04-05          3
6           7           2015-04-06          3
7           7           2015-04-07          NULL
8           7           2015-04-08          NULL
9           7           2015-04-09          NULL
10          9           2015-04-01          2
11          9           2015-04-02          2
12          9           2015-04-03          NULL
13          9           2015-04-04          NULL
14          9           2015-04-05          NULL
15          9           2015-04-06          3
16          9           2015-04-07          4
17          9           2015-04-08          4
18          9           2015-04-09          NULL
19          9           2015-04-10          NULL
```

Comment: can `lag()` have a `partition by` on the AtheleteId?

Comment: Could you add the raw `MedicalAvailabilityStatusId` to the query and share the result? It will help understand what's going on here

Comment: The real trick, from a windowing perspective here is that you have to establish a `group` of records here. A `group` would be composed for `row_index` (1,2,3,4) and (5,6,7,8,9) for example. Then you can apply a `Max(status) OVER (PARTITION BY this_established_group)`. `Lag()` is sort of the right direction here, but unless you can apply that lag recursively until all values are filled, you are sort of stuck with an `islands and gaps` sort of issue to establish the groups. How big is this table? Recursive CTE may make more sense depending on the size.

Comment: @Mureinik sorry that was a bit of a cut and paste typo, fixed now

Comment: @JNevill that makes sense. Sadly this table is about 1.5 million rows. I might look into a rec CTE instead.

Comment: Recursive CTE may be the slower route because of the data size. [Check out this page](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/) on the islands and gaps problem with a tsql focus. The first "Solution" may give you some direction for "Grouping" these records to be able to `Max() OVER` the results.

Comment: thanks @JNevill you pointed me in the right direction. Solution is posted below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props to @jnevill, his comment above about creating a partition pointed me in the correct direct.

My solution was to create a sum column `_grp` which sums the current `status` with the previous `_grp`. Therefore any row with `null` will have the same `_grp` as all the previous nulls back as far as the last non-null `status`. Then we take the max `status` from a partition based on `_grp`, but in any `_grp` partition there should only be one non-null `status`, the first one in the partition (aka the last explicitly defined `status`). I hope that makes sense :)

```
use tempdb

drop table if exists t

create table t(row_index int, AthleteId int, AvailabilityDate datetime, Status int)

insert into t
(row_index   ,AthleteId   ,AvailabilityDate    ,Status)
values
(1  ,7 ,'2015-04-01',2    ),
(2  ,7 ,'2015-04-02',2     ),
(3  ,7 ,'2015-04-03',NULL ),
(4  ,7 ,'2015-04-04',NULL ),
(5  ,7 ,'2015-04-05',3     ),
(6  ,7 ,'2015-04-06',3     ),
(7  ,7 ,'2015-04-07',NULL ),
(8  ,7 ,'2015-04-08',NULL ),
(9  ,7 ,'2015-04-09',NULL ),
(10 ,9 ,'2015-04-01',2     ),
(11 ,9 ,'2015-04-02',2     ),
(12 ,9 ,'2015-04-03',NULL ),
(13 ,9 ,'2015-04-04',NULL ),
(14 ,9 ,'2015-04-05',NULL ),
(15 ,9 ,'2015-04-06',3     ),
(16 ,9 ,'2015-04-07',4     ),
(17 ,9 ,'2015-04-08',4     ),
(18 ,9 ,'2015-04-09',NULL ),
(19 ,9 ,'2015-04-10',NULL );

-- this CTE sums the row by row status (anything with null status is the same _grp as the row above) which creates a suitable partition
   _partitioned (row_index, AthleteId, AvailabilityDate, Status, _grp) AS 
    (
    SELECT
        row_index,
        AthleteId,
        AvailabilityDate,
        Status,
        SUM(Status) OVER (ORDER BY row_index) as _grp
    FROM t
    )

SELECT 
    AthleteId, 
    SportId, 
    AvailabilityDate, 
    Status,
-- this gets the max status in the partition which we created above
    MAX(Status) over (partition by _partitioned.grp order by _partitioned.row_index) as DerivedStatus   
FROM 
    _partitioned
    ORDER BY row_index
```

Answer (score 1):

The `lag()` uses the "before" data to calculate the `lag()`.  It does not use the *calculated* result from the previous row.

Note that in all the following suggestions, I am partitioning by `athleteid`.  Given the nature of the data, this seems reasonable.

What you really want is:

```
select . . ., 
       LAG(Status IGNORE NULLS) over (partition by athleteid order by row_index)  
from @AvailabilityDates ;
```

You can talk to Microsoft about implementing this ISO/ANSI-standard functionality.

Lacking that, one popular method uses `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select . . .,
       ad2.Status
from @AvailabilityDates ad OUTER APPLY
     (select top (1) status
      from @AvailabilityDates ad2
      where ad2.athleteid = ad.athleteid and
            ad2.status is not null and 
            ad2.row_index <= ad.row_index
      order by ad2.row_index desc
     ) ad2;
```

Or, if there are just one or two `NULL`s in a row, you can extend the `COALESCE()`:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(status,
                lag(status, 1) over (partition by athleteid order by row_index),
                lag(status, 2) over (partition by athleteid order by row_index),
                lag(status, 3) over (partition by athleteid order by row_index)
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone explain (like I'm stupid) how to get the behaviour i need?

I also become confused by the windowing functions.  And often fall back on using the super-powerful, and (to me) easy to understand APPLY operators.

```
use tempdb

drop table if exists t

create table t(row_index int, AthleteId int, AvailabilityDate datetime, Status int)

insert into t
(row_index   ,AthleteId   ,AvailabilityDate    ,Status)
values
(1  ,7 ,'2015-04-01',2    ),
(2  ,7 ,'2015-04-02',2     ),
(3  ,7 ,'2015-04-03',NULL ),
(4  ,7 ,'2015-04-04',NULL ),
(5  ,7 ,'2015-04-05',3     ),
(6  ,7 ,'2015-04-06',3     ),
(7  ,7 ,'2015-04-07',NULL ),
(8  ,7 ,'2015-04-08',NULL ),
(9  ,7 ,'2015-04-09',NULL ),
(10 ,9 ,'2015-04-01',2     ),
(11 ,9 ,'2015-04-02',2     ),
(12 ,9 ,'2015-04-03',NULL ),
(13 ,9 ,'2015-04-04',NULL ),
(14 ,9 ,'2015-04-05',NULL ),
(15 ,9 ,'2015-04-06',3     ),
(16 ,9 ,'2015-04-07',4     ),
(17 ,9 ,'2015-04-08',4     ),
(18 ,9 ,'2015-04-09',NULL ),
(19 ,9 ,'2015-04-10',NULL );


select t.*, s.status s2
from t 
outer apply 
 (
    select top 1 status 
    from t t2 
    where t2.AthleteId = t.AthleteId 
      and t2.row_index < t.row_index 
      and status is not null 
    order by row_index desc
  ) s
```